# How can I count the number of times the $i$th element of two lists are equal?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-test

I'm trying to sample $100$ numbers from the Geometric$(0.3)$ distribution, and $100$ numbers from the Geometric$(0.6)$ distribution, and compute
$$\frac{\text{number of times Geom(0.3) value = Geom(0.6) value}}{100}$$
My approach is to do

```
{RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.3], 100], RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.5], 100]}
```

which creates a list of two lists, one containing the samples from Geom(0.3) and the other containing the samples from Geom(0.6). Now I just need to count how many times the $i$th element of the two lists are equal. How can I do that? Or is there a better way to do this whole sampling thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
dist1=RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.3], 100];
dist2= RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.6], 100];

Count[dist1-dist2,0]

Total@UnitBox[dist1-dist2]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[0];

a = RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.3], 10];
b = RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.6], 10];

c = Transpose[{a, b}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {4, 0}, {1, 4}, {6,
> 0}, {1, 1}}

```
Count[{x_, x_}] @ c
```

> 2

```
SequenceCount[c, {x_} /; Equal @@ x]
```

> 2

Answer (score 4):

```
a = RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.3], 10];
b = RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.6], 10];

c = Transpose[{a, b}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {4, 0}, {1, 4}, {6,
> 0}, {1, 1}}

Grabbing the @eldo's data and using `Cases`:

```
Length@Cases[c, {x_ ..}]
```

> 2

Answer (score 4):

Grabbing @eldo's data:

```
SeedRandom[0];

a = RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.3], 10];
b = RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.6], 10];

c = Transpose[{a, b}]

(* {{1, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {4, 0}, {1, 4}, {6, 0}, {1, 1}} *)
```

```
Total[MapApply[KroneckerDelta]@c]

(* 2 *)
```

Or:

```
MapThread[KroneckerDelta, {a, b}] // Total

(* 2 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
m = RandomInteger[GeometricDistribution[0.3], {100, 2}];
Count[ Equal @@@ m, True]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[0];
a = RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.3], 10];
b = RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[0.6], 10]; (* Thanks @eldo )
```

---

```
Subtract @@ {a, b} // Unitize // Count[0]
Count[True]@MapThread[#1 === #2 &, {a, b}]
Count[True][Equal @@@ Transpose[{a, b}]]
ArrayReduce[Apply@SameQ, {a, b}, 1]
```

---

> 2